# A small compatible gpu

Tags: arm, touchscreen

I would like to know what is the best possible way to solve the following problem:

I want to have a touch screen over USB this touch screen should be able to receive Graphics from the attached PC, so there will be a driver installed on the pc itself. The touch screen should be very responsive (almost like most smartphones), can Arduino or Raspberry Pi do this ? Or should I go with ARM chip sets?

Found this on ARM website
http://www.arm.com/markets/embedded/embedded-computing.php
Looks something that i relating to me, but want to know is it abel to recieve the graphics from the attached host (PC)

Comment: First, do some research as to what "receiving graphics" involves.

Comment: where do I start?

Comment: By learning how to generate graphics in a computer program.

Comment: Oh, ok I am actually a programmer so I know .Net (C# and a bit of C++) java too . But have no idea on hardware side, please see edit to my question

Comment: Graphics? Just buttons and Menu, or a movie?

Comment: Lets say movie.

Comment: You'll need a fast interface then. Not easy for a beginner or even a one-man team as there are many components involved.

Comment: Best way is to use an existing solution. There are some USB screens and there are also touch modules to mount on screens.

Comment: @svens yes that is a good point.

Answer (score 2):

For the purpose described, you can dispense with an intermediary Raspberry Pi or Arduino module: The simplest and possibly least expensive application would be a USB touchscreen graphic module, such as those [from Robopeak](http://www.robopeak.com/blog/?cat=7).

[image: Robopeak mini USB touchscreen graphic module]

This is an open source hardware design, available from the usual online sources such as [eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2-8-USB-TFT-Touch-Display-Module-V2-Raspberry-Pi-Cubieboard-pcDuino-MiniPC-/391168845757) (~ US$43+shipping).

There are similar or even much more capable displays if you search on sites like DigiKey for USB color graphic display modules. For instance, the FTDi VM800BU ([datasheet link](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Modules/DS_VM800BU%20EVE.pdf)) sells for [US$69 in single units](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/VM800BU35A-BK/768-1225-ND/4947788).

[image: FTDi USB display module]

These modules incorporate a graphics processor and requisite hardware and software, including an ARM or similar processor, on board. This simplifies the interfacing from the PC to a simple USB data stream - simpler yet if a device driver is available for your operating system of choice.

Comment: Point to note... none of these offer touch capabilities.

Comment: @JackyBoi  Both do: The Robopeak one: "Touch Screen: Resistive Single Point". The FTDi one: "Integrated resistive touch screen LCD panel".